# Match data from structs objects

Tags: go, struct

in the following code (which I re-used from previous question) we need to match objects according to matching **keys** values

> The keys are the value of

From model `internalConfig`

**type**

From external config

**app-type**

In case we have 'match' (in the value) we need to replace the data from the external config and update the internal config

**e.g**. if for zone2 app-type=app1  is equal to internal config type=app1 we need to change the content from external config to be

**from**

```
- name: TEST
  type: app1
  target: ./
```

to (since app1 is equal in internal and external config- we are updating the data from external to internal)

```
- name: TEST
  type: AZURE 
  target: ./
```

given the above data the internal config should look after the match like

**At the end it should look like**

```
- name: TEST
  type: AZURE 
  target: ./

- name: TEST3
  type: HEROKU
  target: ./

- name: TEST2
  type: app3
  target: ./

- name: TEST2
  type: AZURE 
  target: ./
```

Im trying the following but I wasn’t able to match all the objects in case I’ve more then one entry to the same key 
e.g.  app1 “key” is in the first and the last entry, so my code is update only the first entry

```
- name: TEST
  type: app1
  target: ./

- name: TEST3
  type: app2
  target: ./

- name: TEST2
  type: app3
  target: ./

- name: TEST2
  type: app1
  target: ./
```

Any idea how could I resolve this ? this is what i've tried which works **only on the first match**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "log"
)


type InternalConfig struct {
    Models []Imodel `yaml:"models"`
}

type Imodel struct {
    Name   string `yaml:"name"`
    Type   string `yaml:"type"`
    Target string `yaml:"target"`
}

var internalConfig = []byte(`
models:
   - name: TEST
     type: app1
     target: ./

   - name: TEST3
     type: app2
     target: ./

   - name: TEST2
     type: app3
     target: ./

   - name: TEST2
     type: app1
     target: ./
`)

type ExternalConfig struct {
    Landscape Zone `yaml:"Landscape"`
}

type Zone struct {
    Zone   string   `yaml:"zone"`
    Models []Emodel `yaml:"models"`
}

type Emodel struct {
    AppType     string `yaml:"app-type"`
    ServiceType string `yaml:"service-type"`
}

var externalConfig = []byte(`
Landscape:
  zone: zone1
  models:
    - app-type: app1
      service-type: GCP
    - app-type: app2
      service-type: AMAZON
  zone: zone2
  models:
    - app-type: app1
      service-type: AZURE
    - app-type: app2
      service-type: HEROKU
`)

func main() {
    iCfgYaml := InternalConfig{}
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal(internalConfig, &iCfgYaml); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error in model InternalConfig: %v", err)
    }

    eCfgYaml := ExternalConfig{}
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal(externalConfig, &eCfgYaml); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error in model ExternalConfig: %v", err)
    }
    if err := UpdateInternalState(&iCfgYaml, eCfgYaml, "zone2"); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error updating internal config: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("DBG: %+v\n", iCfgYaml)
}

func UpdateInternalState(iCfg *InternalConfig, eCfg ExternalConfig, zone string) error {
    ilm := make(map[string]int)
    for i, v := range iCfg.Models {
        ilm[v.Type] = i
    }
    for _, em := range eCfg.Landscape.Models {
        if eCfg.Landscape.Zone == zone {

            if i, ok := ilm[em.AppType]; ok {
                iCfg.Models[i].Type = em.ServiceType
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

if you run the code above, this is the data you will get

```
{Models:[
{Name:TEST Type:app1 Target:./} 
{Name:TEST3 Type:HEROKU Target:./} 
{Name:TEST2 Type:app3 Target:./} 
{Name:TEST2 Type:AZURE Target:./}]}
```

**The first entry doesn't updated**

https://play.golang.org/p/5f3Ad9Z7fqY

If needs more clarification please let me know

Comment: lots of views :) but as I didnt receive any comment/answer , is that so complicated to achive with golang? in node.js I've used Lodash to deal with this such of scenario but in golang I didnt find something similar which make it a bit harder to handle

Comment: i think it happens because you have 2 struct with `app1` and you update it by using map, so it will only update the last one assigned to the map